# Calling a bash function from a tcl module to change environment

Tags: bash, tcl, environment-modules

I have a bash function `myEnv` which loads several environments and I also use several modules. For example, to set up my environment I may do

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
myEnv program1
myEnv program2
module load program3
module load program4
```

and I would like to take care of all of this in one module. Unfortunately, `tcl` does not support executing `myEnv` to change the environment. Aside from restructuring the way that `myEnv` works, is there a way to call `myEnv` from `tcl` in a single `module` to take care of this?

I would like to write a module, say, `programs1234` so that I can just do `module load programs1234` and take care of the two `myEnv`s and two `module load`s.

Answer (score 0):

Will setting the global env variable suffice for setting environment variables? For example:

```
set env(FOO) "Test variable foo"
set env(BAR) "One more variable"
...
# Execute a tcl program in the env configured above.
exec [info nameofexecutable] -f program3
```

So for example, if program3 prints out env(FOO) and env(BAR), you'll see these values.

```
puts $env(FOO)
puts $env(BAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

A modulefile may define specific shell content (other than the regular environment variable definitions) to evaluate in your current shell session.

This shell content should be directly sent to the stdout channel with Tcl `puts` command.

It will be included in the shell code produced by the `modulecmd` script which is then evaluated in the current shell session.

The `programs1234` modulefile you want to write may look like:

```
#%Module
puts stdout {myEnv program1}
puts stdout {myEnv program2}
module load program3
module load program4
```